# Program python socket

Tags: python, sockets, server

I have an issue in this Python code. Please help me. Thank you

```
import sys
import socket
import select

HOST = 'sys.ase.ro'
SOCKET_LIST = []
RECV_BUFFER = 4096
PORT = 6508


def chat_server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)

    SOCKET_LIST.append(server_socket)

    print "Chat server started on port " + str(PORT)

    while 1:


        ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(SOCKET_LIST, [], [], 0)

        for sock in ready_to_read:

            if sock == server_socket:

                sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()

                SOCKET_LIST.append(sockfd)
                print "Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr

                broadcast(server_socket, sockfd, "[%s:%s] entered our chatting room\n" % addr)


            else:

                try:

                    data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                    if data:

                        broadcast(server_socket, sock, "\r" + '[' + str(sock.getpeername()) + '] ' + data)
                    else:

                        if sock in SOCKET_LIST:
                            SOCKET_LIST.remove(sock)


                        broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr)


                except:
                    broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr)
                    continue

    server_socket.close()


# broadcast chat messages to all connected clients
def broadcast(server_socket, sock, message):
    for socket in SOCKET_LIST:

        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock:
            try:
                socket.send(message)
            except:

                socket.close()

                if socket in SOCKET_LIST:
                    SOCKET_LIST.remove(socket)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit()
```

The error looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/chat_server.py", line 90, in
<module>
sys.exit(chat_server())   File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/chat_server.py", line 20, in
chat_server
server_socket.bind((HOST,PORT))   File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 222, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) socket.error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Comment: are you sure you posted the right version of your code?
there is no line `sys.exit(chat_server())` in your example

Comment: You're right. The only difference is that i forgot to put chat_server. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind a socket to remote address. 
From [windows documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind):

> The bind function associates a local address with a socket.

use [connect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect) instead:

```
server_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

Comment: It doesn't work. This error is now : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: it is working and trying to connect to `sys.ase.ro` the way you wrote it, but it doesn't get a response. Are you sure you are supposed to use that server? Your question is not very clear, what you are trying to achieve. My answer only solves the problem from the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I find out why it dosen't work
The reason for why my code fails tho is because i'm trying to bind to an external hostname.
My machine is not aware of this hostname hence the error message. I change it in localhost and it works.